# Where to write code for pr2 robot simulator?

Tags: ros, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So at this link: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_script , commands for making the pr2 robot simulator perform certain actions are given. Where would I write this code and how would I run it so that the pr2 robot on the gazebo simulator performed these tasks?

Detailed instructions would be appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227969/where-to-write-code-for-pr2-robot-simulator?/) by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot_script package was experimental and is no longer supported. Please follow the tutorials as suggested (and previously: http://answers.ros.org/question/227339/what-to-do-on-the-pr2-robot-simulation/ )

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1